# Undefined reference to symbol but library is linked

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, opencv3.0

I am trying to build an application with opencv 3.0 and I get an "undefined reference to symbol error"

My problem is that the symbol is defined within the libraries I am linking to.

Compile command:

```
g++ -o DisparityMap main.o tools.o emb.o moc_tools.o moc_emb.o -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_calib3d -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
```

The error I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: twowindow.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv'
//usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But the symbol in question is actually defined within the libraries I link to:

```
scanelf -l -s _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv | grep _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv

ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.0.0 
ET_DYN _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so.3.0.0
```

Comment: OpenCV and Qt built with same compiler?

Comment: Also, make sure your libraries are in the correct order on the link line.  A library can only depend on libraries that come after it on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

> Compile command:

This is *not* a compile command, it's a *link* command.

> The error I get:

The error is referencing `twowindow.o`, which is *not* on your link command.

Therefore, it is very hard to believe that the error is really coming from the link command you gave.

Most likely, the error is coming from a *different* link command, and *that* link command does not have `-lopencv_core` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Before linking the libraries, give the path of those with -L flag.